# Windows Phone 8 SDK on VHD Boot

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have installed Windows 8 on VHD.

After boot from VHD I installed visual studio and Now trying to install windows 8 SDK.

It get failed everytime. Does VHD boot is the reason for that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this to develop Windows phone 8 Application. then the Minimal Requirement for that is WIndows 8 Professional or Higher with 4 GB RAM in your System.

and if your System meets the requirement then you can directly download Windows phone 8 SDK first then there is no need to install visual studio. it wil get update automatically.

Comment: I have tried following way. When I did VHD boot it did not work but when I did separate partition installation it did work.

Comment: Okkk dot,  I think you got your soution..  :)